# prime numbers of given range in c using loops only

Tags: c, loops

how can i write a program which going to give all prime no of given range WITHOUT using ANY conditions (using just loops!) in c language. i tried many different options but non of them works properly...
for instance:

what i have already tried:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define UNTIL 1000
#define NOT_INCLUDED 2
int main()
{
int prime =1, i =1,factor=0;

    for(prime=1;UNTIL>=prime ;prime++)
    {
        for( i=1;i<=prime;i++)
        {
            for(;prime%i==0;)
            {
                factor++;
            }
        }

        for(;factor==2;factor=0)
        {
            printf("prime number: %d \n",prime);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show us those different (compilable) options and tell us where they fail.

Comment: Hint: Every loop has a condition. It's up to you to use this condition wisely.

Comment: This seems silly. Loops run until a condition/conditions are met.

Comment: The not-so-obvious answer: *carefully*. The very obvious question: *Why would you want to ?*

Comment: #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define UNTIL 1000
#define NOT_INCLUDED 2
int main()
{

 int prime =1, i =1,factor=0;
 
 
 
 
 
 for(prime=1;UNTIL>=prime ;prime++)
 {
  for( i=1;i<=prime;i++)
  {
   for(;prime%i==0;)
   {
    factor++;
   }
   
  }
 
 
 
 

  for(;factor==2;factor=0)
  {
   printf("prime number: %d \n",prime);
   
  }
 }
 
 
 
 
 return 0;

}
this is what i have tried mates

Comment: The question seems either trivial or impossible depending on one's reading of the question. If "conditions" means "if statements" then any standard implementation can be modified (e.g. `if(a)b;` becomes `while(a){b;break;}`). If "conditions" means _conditional expressions as defined by the language grammar_, then you can't use loops either, because they all contain conditional expressions. Perhaps recursion and `switch` statements are in order?

Answer (score 2):

Challenge accepted: **no conditions, hidden or otherwise**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // atoi

int main(void) {
    const char *p = "2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29\0\0\0\0\0"; /* extend at will */
    for (;;) {
        p += printf("%d ", atoi(p));
        fflush(stdout);
        int z = 42 / *p;
        (void)z; /* unused warning */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

see code running on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/0Hylrb)

Answer (score 0):

To check if `N` is prime, iterate through all the numbers from `2` to `N` to see if `N` is divisible by any other number. Every number is divisible by `1`, so when you are testing numbers for prime, start testing against `2`.

Example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_prime(int N)
{
    //0 and 1 are not primes
    if (N < 2)
        return 0;

    //start testing against 2
    for(int i = 2; i < N; i++) 
        if(N % i == 0)
            return 0; //not a prime

    return 1; //prime
}

int main()
{
    printf("Primes from 0 to 1000:\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        if(is_prime(i))
            printf("%d, ", i);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

You can optimize the loop by changing the range to `N/2`.

```
for(int i = 2; i <= N/2; i++) 
    if(N % i == 0)
        return 0; //not a prime
return 1;//prime
```